# High Disk usage when writing to sqlite database

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

I are running a local server which is using sqlite as database. When insert or update operations are happening disk usage goes very high(around 95%). The device becomes unusable. All database requests come from multiple threads which perform atomic db operations.

I have tried different pragma operations which improved speed of execution but the disk usage is still very high. Since request come from multiple threads I cannot use transactions.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are just loading it too much....  In what range is the amount of inserted data here? And how many indexes need to be updated?

Comment: whenever db call happens it happens in groups of around 30-50 calls.

Comment: Reads or writes?

Comment: both. Roughly 50% of both reads and writes